# Creating shopping cart website,subprice problems

Tags: javascript, php, html

[shopping cart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lx1Rn.png)

I want to create subprice function that shows at the colomn, but i dont know how to print the subprice from the quantity below the first id, please help me :D
this code is to shows the subprice

```
<div class="col-sm-2 text-center" id="test">
  <script>
    $("input[name=quantity0]").on("keydown",function(){
    id= "<?php echo $id ;?>";
    var price;
    quantity=$("input[name=quantity0]").val();
    for(i=0;i<carts.length;i++){
    if(id==1){
      price=30;
      total=price*quantity;
      $("#test").text("$"+total);
    }
    if(id==2){
      price=30;
      total=price*quantity;
      $("#test").text("$"+total);
    }
    if(id==3){
      price=30;
      total=price*quantity;
      $("#test").text("$"+total);
    }
    if(id==4){
      price=30;
      total=price*quantity;
      $("#test").text("$"+total);
    }
    if(id==5){
      price=30;
      total=price*quantity;
      $("#test").text("$"+total);
    }
    if(id==6){
      price=30;
      total=price*quantity;
      $("#test").text("$"+total);
    }
    if(id==7){
      price=30;
      total=price*quantity;
      $("#test").text("$"+total);
    }
    if(id==8){
      price=30;
      total=price*quantity;
      $("#test").text("$"+total);
    }
    if(id==9){
      price=30;
      total=price*quantity;
      $("#test").text("$"+total);
    }
    if(id==10){
      price=30;
      total=price*quantity;
      $("#test").text("$"+total);
    }
  }
  });
  </script>
</div>
```

i uploaded it on my website http://scellion.hol.es/ in case you guys need to try to understand the problems :D

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: uploading my code now

Comment: ummm im new here, can you guys tell me how to create code box? :D

Comment: @Sam_ tab 4 times in the box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you should reengineer your code first, at the moment it's hard for us answer precisely to your question. I don't know your experience level but i will give you some tip.

**SWITCH CASE**

Instead of this:

```
if(id==1){
  price=30;
  total=price*quantity;
  $("#test").text("$"+total);
}
if(id==2){
  price=30;
  total=price*quantity;
  $("#test").text("$"+total);
}
if(id==3){
  price=30;
  total=price*quantity;
  $("#test").text("$"+total);
}
if(id==4){
  price=30;
  total=price*quantity;
  $("#test").text("$"+total);
}
```

You should use this:

```
switch(id):{
    case 1:{
         price=30;
         total=price*quantity;
         $("#test").text("$"+total);
         break;
    }

    case 2:{
         price=30;
         total=price*quantity;
         $("#test").text("$"+total);
         break;
    }

    case 3:{
         price=30;
         total=price*quantity;
         $("#test").text("$"+total);
         break;
    }


    case 4:{
         price=30;
         total=price*quantity;
         $("#test").text("$"+total);
         break;
    }

    default:{

    }
}
```

**CREATE FUNCTION**

Instead of copy and paste the same code, you should create a function. Functions are also useful for software maintenance. Example:

```
function setText(){

         price=30;
         total=price*quantity;
         $("#test").text("$"+total);
}

switch(id):{
    case 1:{
         setText();
         break;
    }

    case 2:{
         setText();
         break;
    }

    case 3:{
         setText();
         break;
    }


    case 4:{
         setText();
         break;
    }

    default:{

    }
}
```

Anyway, if i understand the problem, this is a code that i tested on your site in the browser console and it seems to work:

```
//THIS IS FOR INTERCEPT VALUE CHANGE (UP AND DOWN)
$("input[name=quantity0]").bind('keyup mouseup', function () {

    //JUST FOR TESTING, BUT YOU NEED TO TAKE THE REAL PRICE OF THE ITEM
    var priceSingleUnit = 30;

    //THIS.VALUE ---> TAKES THE VALUE OF THE INPUT FIELD
    if(!(this.value <= 0)){
    $("#test").text("$" + (this.value * priceSingleUnit));
    }

});
```

Useful links:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Comment: Thank you for the tips , im still new in web programming as well this is a project from  lecturer to create shopping cart  without database